# Setting BaseURLs per subfolder with Jekyll (GitHub Pages)

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, base-url

Is there a way to append a specific value to `site.baseurl` in different subfolders? For instance, I have two different subfolders each using a specific language (`lang`), and I want to append this value to `site.baseurl` for pages and documents in the subfolder. So for example,

- `A.md` in subfolder `lang1` would have the BaseURL of `/my_site_url/lang1/`, and
- `B.md` in subfolder `lang2` would have the BaseURL of `/my_site_url/lang2/`.

Is this possible with GitHub Pages, without build+serving my site locally beforehand?

**Edit :** I need BaseURLs for managing a Navigation Bar that goes through all individual pages in a subfolder. In such a case, prepending `site.baseurl` with the subfolder appended beforehand would be the most economic choice?

Comment: Have you tried using `permalinks` in your front matter to control the URLs? https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

Comment: I have, but the `baseurl` is for using a navigation bar. Permalinks don't seem to be enough, I'm afraid. Should've clarified it in the original post, sorry.

Comment: Would cycling through your `site.posts` and building `href`s from each `post.url` be sufficient for building your navigation bar?  You can even do some logic on portions of the `post.url`, if you are looking for only parts of the URL for each post (e.g. `/lang1` of a url of `/lang1/A.html`)

Comment: I don't know much about the `_posts` directory, but would I be right to assume that you suggest moving the contents of both `lang` subfolders to the `_posts` directory, and then cycling through via HTML's uasge of loop statements? Unfortunately I have subdirectories in each language as well, may I trouble you by asking whether the looping of `site.posts` can produce `class="opener"` if necessary as well?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I incorrectly used `site.posts`, which implies markdown files in `_posts` directory.  Since you are using custom directories, you could define a layout for each directory https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/.  You would then do things like `{% assign langOnePages = site.pages | where: 'layout', 'lang1' %}`.  When you cycle through `langOnePages`, I expect each `page.url` will have `/lang1` in the url.  Hopefully this is helpful, I'm mostly just throwing out some ideas to see if you can make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**_config.yml**

```
    baseUrl: /sub
    lang1Url: /lang1
    lang2Url: /lang2
```

**nav.html, footer.html**

```html
    <li><a href="{{ site.baseUrl }}{{ site.lang1Url }}/index.html">Home - lang 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ site.baseUrl }}{{ site.lang2Url }}/index.html">Home - lang 2</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My goal, however, is to use whatever language the current page uses and link pages of corresponding language only on the sidebar, which is why I need a flexible BaseURL configuration.

Comment: Well then you can set the currentLang in front matter for each page and check the variable on sidebar partial and show links conditionally @PaulKim

Comment: Could I trouble you a little more as to whether this "front matter" can be preset in a different config file for each subdirectory?

Comment: I suppose, for each post you have to mention the language in front matter. This way you can do the find and replace inside each folder and set the language once for that folder to save time @PaulKim